# XPATH selection in Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm stuck  looking at scraping some data here https://internet.safaricom.co.ke/faqs/home. I'm keen on getting the  questions and answers  in Pandas, thus a Python scraper is my preference. I followed this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://internet.safaricom.co.ke/5g-wireless/coverage'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)


# Wait for the table to be loaded
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="5G-coverage"]')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'), 'html.parser')

#Extract the table data using Pandas
dfs = pd.read_html(str(soup))
df = dfs[0]
```

The  code seems to work well in extracting the table details. How can I have the  XPATH right for this page  https://internet.safaricom.co.ke/faqs/home that takes care of the collapsible  parts? Output is just a Pandas df with one column with question and the other with Answer for  each of  the  FAQs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you inspect the page in your browser you can see all the elements, whether they are collapsed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refer the below working code with explanation:**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
URL = "https://internet.safaricom.co.ke/faqs/home"
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
time.sleep(3)

# Store the locator of dropdown parent <div> element
collapsible_parts = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'simple-tabpanel-0')))
# Parse it into soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(collapsible_parts.get_attribute('outerHTML'), 'html.parser')
# print the text
print(soup.text)
```

**Console Result:**

```
What are the Safaricom Home “HOME PLUS” Plans?These are integrated Voice Minutes, mobile Data and SMS bundles, availed alongside your preferred HOME Fibre plans, and that allow you to choose a bundle that meets you and your loved ones’ needs.The bundles also come with a FREE 2GB YouTube bundle and free access to WhatsApp after the data bundle is fully utilized and is within the validity period, so that you can continue keeping in touch.What “Home Plus” bundles are available?PackagePriceBundleHOME PLUS 800Ksh. 8008GB + 400Min + 1000SMSHOME PLUS 1800Ksh.1,80017GB + 1000Min + 2000SMSHOME PLUS 2700Ksh. 2,70027GB + 1500Min + 3000SMSHOME PLUS 4600Ksh.4,60047GB + 2500Min + 5000SMSAll bundles are valid for 30 days All bundles come with a 2GB Free YouTube bundle and Free WhatsApp access upon full utilization of the data bundle Customers will be able to share the bundle resources with members of their householdHow do I purchase the “Home Plus” bundles?Dial *400# select “Get Home Plus” and choose your preferred bundle. Alternatively, on MySafaricom App, go to Home Internet, select Safaricom Home Fiber, then 'Share Home Plus' to purchase a Home Plus plan.Will the bundles auto renew?Yes, the bundles will auto renew after the 30-day validity period.Will I be able to share the minutes, data and SMS resources with other mobile numbers?Yes, dial *400# and select “Share Home Plus” or visit MySafaricom app, Select Safaricom Home Fibre, Home internet and click 'Share Home Plus' to input the mobile numbers of your desired beneficiaries.Will the “Home Plus” resources rollover?No, Home Plus resources will not rollover.Do the “Home Plus” resources expire?Yes, Unutilized resources will expire on 30th day past 23:59 hours.How do I add or delete a beneficiary?Dial *400# and select “Share Home Plus” or on MySafaricom app, go to Safaricom Home Fiber then Home internet. Click on 'Share Home Plus' to change your beneficiaries.How many beneficiaries can I add?You can add up to 5 beneficiaries to access the shared resources.Can I purchase 2 different “Home Plus” bundles for different amounts within the same month?Yes. You can purchase different bundles within the month. The last one you will settle on, will be the one to be renewed once 30 days elapse.Can I purchase the “Home Plus” bundles for another number?You can only add another number as a beneficiary. You will not be able to purchase Home Plus for another number.What should I do if I purchase a bundle erroneously?Please contact the contact center on 400 for assistance and for the reversal to be affected.What are the available payment channels?1. USSD : dial *400# select “Home Plus” and after selecting your preferred bundle, follow the prompts to make payment 2. MySafaricom app : download from your Playstore or AppStore and select the Safaricom Home Fiber option under Home Intenet In case I need more information or assistance, which channels can I use?For assistance, please call 400 from the number that you used to pay for the service. Alternatively, you can send an email to safaricomhome@safaricom.co.ke. You can also reach us on social media: 1. Twitter: @Safaricom_Care2. Facebook: Safaricom PLC 3. Zuri: WhatsApp or save mobile number 0722 000100 on your contacts, open chat and type ‘Hi Zuri’ 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. This largely works. I had to add a few code snippets to collect it in a format that I wanted.  I tried the same approach with this  link https://www.safaricom.co.ke/media-center-landing/frequently-asked-questions/m-pesa-bulk-payment-b2c and seems  I'm wrong somewhere. I can get the questions but seems  this class card-body in collapse show cannot  be  accessed. Are you able to help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://internet.safaricom.co.ke/faqs/home'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panel1a-header"]')))

element.click()

expanded_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panel1a-content"]/div/p')))

print(expanded_element.text)
```

Result:

```
These are integrated Voice Minutes, mobile Data and SMS bundles, availed alongside your preferred HOME Fibre plans, and that allow you to choose a bundle that meets you and your loved ones’ needs.
The bundles also come with a FREE 2GB YouTube bundle and free access to WhatsApp after the data bundle is fully utilized and is within the validity period, so that you can continue keeping in touch.
```